# Delete key not working in ubuntu 10.04

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, ubuntu-10.04

I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu 10.04 running on a Dell Latitude D630 laptop and everything was  working fine till I tried to change "Alt+Ctrl+Delete" to be system monitor rather than logout screen.

But I failed to change it, so I restored everything as it was before but I found that the Delete key was not working. I login to Windows 7 and it's working fine.

I tried to use the command **xev** to see what the key code for it is but it doesn't give me any response. The result is:

```
KeymapNotify event, serial 36, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  18  0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I found a similar issue and the solution was to add this line to startup applications:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 242 = Delete"
```

but I can't get the keycode for my delete.

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

Check again the place where you configured keyboard shortcuts. You probably accidentally bound <kbd>Delete</kbd> to a function with no immediately visible effect. Global shortcuts take effect before `xev` can see the events.